# Else statement not running? Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a code, that I implented onCreate in the MainActivity, and the problem is, that my code is not fully running, I mean the program only checks the if statement, and don't care about the else statement. Here's the code.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        if(input.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {

            check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

When I start the activity, my button gets invisible, and no matter what I'm writing in the editText field, my button is not gets visible. As I see, the application is don't care about the else statement, only the If.

Maybe I have to repeat somehow this code? In every second? To make sure that the program is checking that editText field is empty or not? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Code in `onCreate` only gets called once when the `Activity` is first created. If you want to periodically check this then you will have to use a timer or a thread perhaps...

Comment: What is `R`? Once you retrieve them, can you confirm `input` and `check` are valid? @Willis brings up a good point that it's called only once, do you have an event like `OnChange` that you can use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    if(input.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

         }});
```

Comment: @user3242849 also note that `CharSequence` returned by `getText` has a `getLength`, and `""` is 0-length in all languages I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener for text changes and set visibility on text event:

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(input.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```